# How to change the color of an equation?

Tags: equations, color, amsmath

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper,svgnames,x11names]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia,sfscaled]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\color{MidnightBlue}}

\begin{document} 
\section*{Reihen} 
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \text{bzw.} a_k=\sum_{n=0}^k a_n
\end{equation*}
$\rightarrow$ kann konvergieren oder divergieren \\
Bedingungen f\"ur Konvergenz:
\begin{itemize}
    \item{Nullfolge} $a_n\rightarrow 0$
    \item{Quotientenkriterium} $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=q$ 
    \begin{align*}
    q<1&\Rightarrow \text{konvergent} \\
    q>1&\Rightarrow \text{divergent} \\
    q=1&\Rightarrow \text{keine Aussage}
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Why aren't my equation blue too using `\everymath`? And how will they?

Comment: Might be an idea to add `xcolor` to your packages, otherwise `MidnightBlue` is not supported  (are you working with `beamer`? given the class options)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik even the displayed equation? That remains black for me

Comment: @daleif Ooh, sorry, I overlooked that one...

Comment: I'll delete my ignorant comments then. :)

Comment: @gvgramazio always a good idea to test if able

Comment: As mentioned adding `xcolor` then the coloring works on all but `equation(*)`, the latter can be fixed by adding the `etoolbox` package and adding `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{orange}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{orange}}`

Comment: @daleif, why it doesn't work `\everymath` then?

Comment: @gvgramazio beats me

Comment: @daleif do you mean that I should try to find out myself and then propose my thoughts or that you don't know? (sorry but I'm not a mother tongue)

Comment: @gvgramazio I have no idea why it is like that. I have called for reinforcements  (some people that know more about it, hopefully they can explain it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78642/discussion-between-gvgramazio-and-daleif).

Comment: Try with `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}`

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper,svgnames,x11names]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utopia,sfscaled]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{MidnightBlue}}

\begin{document} 
\section*{Reihen} 
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \text{bzw.} a_k=\sum_{n=0}^k a_n
\end{equation*}
$\rightarrow$ kann konvergieren oder divergieren \\
Bedingungen f\"ur Konvergenz:
\begin{itemize}
    \item{Nullfolge} $a_n\rightarrow 0$
    \item{Quotientenkriterium} $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=q$ 
    \begin{align*}
    q<1&\Rightarrow \text{konvergent} \\
    q>1&\Rightarrow \text{divergent} \\
    q=1&\Rightarrow \text{keine Aussage}
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I simply invoked the `xcolor`package.

Comment: But it doesn't colour the `equation*` content.

Comment: It seems that the command `\everymath{\color{MidnightBlue}}` doesn't reach the `equation` environment. In that case, change that line by `\begin{equation*} \color{MidnightBlue}`. Another approach is to define a new environment based on `equation` that applies the desired color.

Comment: Indeed;  daleif gave one way to fix this in the comments above.